# How do you integrate Resque in Cucumber features?

Tags: cucumber, resque

I've been trying to apply [Square's method of including Resque in their integration tests](http://corner.squareup.com/2010/08/cucumber-and-resque.html) without much luck. I'm not sure if Resque and/or Cucumber has changed a lot since August 2010.

**Below you find the approach I took, and perhaps you can either:**

1. Tell me where I went wrong, and how I can fix it
2. Recommend a completely new way of integrating Resque into Cucumber features

## What I did to install it

Square's blog post didn't have explicit steps on how to install it, so this is what I did:

1. Downloaded [their gist](http://gist.github.com/532100) into `features/support/cucumber_external_resque_worker.rb`
2. Created a Rails initializer at `config/initializers/cucumber_external_resque.rb` that did the following:

   1. `require 'features/support/cucumber_external_resque_worker'`
   2. `CucumberExternalResqueWorker.install_hooks_on_startup`
3. In `cucumber_external_resque_worker.rb`, I changed instances of `Rails.env.cucumber?` to `Rails.env.test?` because Cucumber was running the features in the `test` environment (I did some `puts Rails.env` in `cucumber_external_resque_worker.rb` to be sure.
4. I run the features. At this point, I get stuck because I get the error `uninitialized constant WorkerBase (NameError)`. Perhaps Resque has changed the way it names things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WorkerBase is part of Bluth (https://github.com/delano/bluth).. A simple queuing system built on Redis.. maybe Square uses it.

Comment: Anyone have any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just run the Resque job synchronously by setting

```
Resque.inline = true
```

I added this line to my `config/initializers/resque.rb`:

```
Resque.inline = Rails.env.test?
```

It's more concise than the other approaches suggested in the post. As it is synchronous, it will be a little slower.

Comment: Thanks yes! I believe this is a semi-recent addition. I've been using this and it works great!

Comment: Did you use the `WorkerBase` class as well?

Comment: @Trip No, I didn't use `WorkerBase`

Answer (score 3):

I spent a while toying with this today, and I think I have a solution.

Here's an updated [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1202190) that removes the need for WorkerBase.

It also includes the config changes necessary to get things working (which are identical to the changes you discovered).

---

```rb
# This is adapted from this gist: https://gist.github.com/532100 by Square
# The main difference is that it doesn't require Bluth for WorkerBase
# It also calls prune_dead_workers on start so it doesn't hang on every other run
# It does not do anything special to avoid connecting to your main redis instance; you should be
# doing that elsewhere

class CucumberExternalResqueWorker
  DEFAULT_STARTUP_TIMEOUT = 1.minute
  COUNTER_KEY = "cucumber:counter"

  class << self
    attr_accessor :pid, :startup_timeout

    def start
      # Call from a Cucumber support file so it is run on startup
      return unless Rails.env.test?
      if self.pid = fork
        start_parent
        wait_for_worker_to_start
      else
        start_child
      end
    end

    def install_hooks_on_startup
      # Call from a Rails initializer
      return unless Rails.env.test?
      # Because otherwise crashed workers cause a fork and we pause the actual worker forever
      Resque::Worker.all.each { |worker| worker.prune_dead_workers }
      install_pause_on_start_hook
      install_worker_base_counter_patch
    end

    def process_all
      # Call from a Cucumber step
      unpause
      sleep 1 until done?
      pause
    end

    def incr
      Resque.redis.incr(COUNTER_KEY)
    end

    def decr
      Resque.redis.decr(COUNTER_KEY)
    end

    def reset_counter
      Resque.redis.set(COUNTER_KEY, 0)
    end

    private

    def done?
      Resque.redis.get(CucumberExternalResqueWorker::COUNTER_KEY).to_i.zero?
    end

    def pause(pid = self.pid)
      return unless Rails.env.test?
      Process.kill("USR2", pid)
    end

    def unpause
      return unless Rails.env.test?
      Process.kill("CONT", pid)
    end

    def start_parent
      at_exit do
        #reset_counter
        Process.kill("KILL", pid) if pid
      end
    end

    def start_child
      # Array form of exec() is required here, otherwise the worker is not a direct child process of cucumber.
      # If it's not the direct child process then the PID returned from fork() is wrong, which means we can't
      # communicate with the worker.
      exec('rake', 'resque:work', "QUEUE=*", "RAILS_ENV=test", "VVERBOSE=1")
    end

    def wait_for_worker_to_start
      self.startup_timeout ||= DEFAULT_STARTUP_TIMEOUT
      start = Time.now.to_i
      while (Time.now.to_i - start) < startup_timeout
        return if worker_started?
        sleep 1
      end

      raise "Timeout while waiting for the worker to start. Waited #{startup_timeout} seconds."
    end

    def worker_started?
      Resque.info[:workers].to_i > 0
    end

    def install_pause_on_start_hook
      Resque.before_first_fork do
        #reset_counter
        pause(Process.pid)
      end
    end

    def install_worker_base_counter_patch
      Resque.class_eval do
        class << self
          def enqueue_with_counters(*args, &block)
            CucumberExternalResqueWorker.incr
            enqueue_without_counters(*args, &block)
          end
          alias_method_chain :enqueue, :counters
        end
      end
      Resque::Job.class_eval do
        def perform_with_counters(*args, &block)
          perform_without_counters(*args, &block)
        ensure
          CucumberExternalResqueWorker.decr
        end
        alias_method_chain :perform, :counters
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the Cucumber environment file `features/support/env.rb`

After:

```rb
require 'cucumber/rails'
```

Add:

```rb
require 'lib/cucumber_external_resque_worker'
CucumberExternalResqueWorker.start
```

Change:

```rb
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

to:

```rb
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

Also, create a file: `config/initializers/cucumber_external_resque.rb`

```rb
require 'lib/cucumber_external_resque_worker'
CucumberExternalResqueWorker.install_hooks_on_startup
```

```rb
# In my controller, I have:
  def start
    if params[:job] then
      Resque.enqueue(DemoJob, j.id)
    end
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end
# DemoJob:
class DemoJob
  def self.queue
    :demojob
  end
  def perform(job_id)
    j = Job.find(job_id)
    j.value = "done"
    j.save
  end
```

```
# In your actual Cucumber step file, for instance:
When /I click the start button for "([^"]*)"/ do |jobname|
  CucumberExternalResqueWorker.reset_counter
  Resque.remove_queue(DemoJob.queue)
  click_button(jobname)
end
When /all open jobs are processed/ do
  CucumberExternalResqueWorker.process_all
end

# And you cucumber feature file looks like:
# Scenario: Starting a job
#   When I click the start button for "Test Job 1"
#     And all open jobs are processed
#   Then I am on the job index page
#     And I should see an entry for "Test Job 1" with a value of "done".
```

Comment: Why do you create an initializer when you can just put that loading stuff in your env.rb?

Comment: This works for me, but only intermittently. Most of the time the process_all method just hangs :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the approach described here:

[Cucumber and Resque Jobs](http://www.anthonyeden.com/2010/10/cucumber-and-resque-jobs/)

which performs the resque processing synchronously. In my case, I'm not interested in testing Resque, I just want to test the functionality in my application.

Comment: Thanks. I know about this, and used it in place of the method above, for now. But I want to run integration tests after all -- and that means the whole stack.